# Failed creating java C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll

Tags: java, tomcat, service, tomcat7

I have an issue when i start tomcat 7 services

```
[2017-07-17 10:56:49] [info]  [ 4384] Starting service...
[2017-07-17 10:56:49] [error] [ 4384] %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
[2017-07-17 10:56:49] [error] [ 4384] Failed creating java C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
[2017-07-17 10:56:49] [error] [ 4384] %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
[2017-07-17 10:56:49] [error] [ 4384] ServiceStart returned 1
[2017-07-17 10:56:49] [error] [ 4384] %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
[2017-07-17 10:56:49] [info]  [  760] Run service finished.
[2017-07-17 10:56:49] [info]  [  760] Commons Daemon procrun finished
```

Last time i used this way to fix this thing in jdk 1.6 and tomcat 6 by copy msvcr71.dll from jdk to tomcat folder and to system32. but for this jdk 1.7 does not have mscvr71.dll and only have msvcr100.dll.

is msvcr71.dll and msvcr100.dll are same ? because i tried to copy the msvcr100.dll from jdk folder to tomcat 7 folder, it doesn't work. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problems occurs becouse :

1 - Tomcat server version is 64-bit but using a 32-bit version of the JVM.
2 - Tomcat server version is 32-bit but using a 64-bit version of the JVM.

Make sure the path of 'jvm.dll' (tab 'Java' when starting tomcat${version}w.exe) locates the right Java Runtime Environment version (x64 or x86).

1. Install jre-8u91-windows-i586.exe. It will gets installed on C:\Program Files (x86).
2. Copy msvcr100.dll and msvcr120.dll files from C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_91\bin

or if you are using Tomcat server version is 64-bit then use JDK 64 bit.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, i tried to use jdk 1.8 can works now :)

Comment: @AnshulSharma Where to copy msvcr100.dll and msvcr120.dll file from to where ??